# How to redirect to valid page if got 'The resource cannot be found'? Please suggest

Tags: web-services, iis, asmx, .net-framework-version, iis-10

I have a requirement to catch this exception or show some log if browse with below invalid filename :

http://localhost/ABC/xyx.asmx

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /.asmx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4261.0

Answer (score 0):

In web.config, you have two methods to custom error page.

When the error is caused by IIS or any other but not asp.net, IIS will shows error page like these.
[image: This page doesn't contain error message.]
[image: This page is to show detailed error message]

If you want to change them, check the custom error pages in Error Pages module. Then delete the existing status code and corresponding page path, and add a new one.
[image]

When the error is caused by the asp.net, IIS will show error page like yello screen of death(YSOD). You can change it in  section. If you want to show custom error page to remote visitor and YSOD to local vistor, you can set mode to RemoteOnly. You can configure this in .NET Error Pages Module.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am facing 'Resource Not found' issue. It does not shows IIS related Error pages.  Is IIS throws this error? If I want to redirect to a valid page, what will be the solution? Please suggest.

Comment: I think your error is caused by IIS, the page is YSOD. So you can set <CustomError  defaultRedirect="xxxx"> and it's sub-section is about status code like <error statusCode="404" redirect="xxxxx" />. You can follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs#configuring-which-error-page-is-displayed) to set.